# Отправка GET запроса на другой домен javascript

Tags: javascript, https, xhr

Необходимо сделать отправку GET запроса на другой домен, стандартная реализация не проходит, которую я ниже написал. Напишите пожалуйста, что нужно поменять в моем коде.

Есть мысли добавить в заголовки следующие строки, только все равно не работает

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://google.com

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type

Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400

```js
let XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest; 
let xhr = new XHR();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://google.com', true); 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://google.com');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
xhr.onload = function() {alert( 'Успешно! '); }
xhr.onerror = function() { console.log( `Ошибка ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}` ); } 
xhr.send();
```

Comment: А что именно не проходит, какая ошибка приходит?

Comment: Добавил возможность онлайн отладки кода, Ошибка код ответа 0